# SQLite3: database disk image is malformed in a certain scenario

Tags: sqlite

**Concerns**:

- SQLite 3.7.12.1 / C++
- SQLITE_OS_OTHER = 1 (synch methods provided)
- SQLITE_THREADSAFE = 1
- journal_mode = MEMORY;

**Scenario**:

1. DB Pool "A" with table A1 (r/w) created in RAM.
2. DB Pool "B" with FTS4 table B1 (r/w) created on flash/hdd. The A1 is attached read-only to this pool.

**A1** is continually updated in one thread (transactions). **B1** is updated in the other thread (transactions) but the updates depend on A1 query selects. While B1 is updated (inserts/updates/deletes) and A1 is modified same time, many times the following error occurs: "database disk image is malformed" and next transactions fail with errors: "cannot start transaction in transaction".

**Question**:

What causes the first error? The A1 is read-only in B1 queries. Though the transactions are independent and they are not required to be synch. This error doesn't appear when I synch the all transactions with external mutex.

Comment: Are both databases configured this way?

Comment: Yes, they are. The DB Pools are created in one application but in different threads.

Comment: How have you implemented the file locking?

Comment: We use SQLite file locking system. We provide only our mutex implementation.

Comment: What OS and fs are you using?

Comment: System: linux, FS: fts3/4.

Comment: For flash/hdd: fts3/4
For RAM: custom.

Comment: These are not file systems.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ext3/ext4. I spent too much time with "fts" features in SQLite :). The B1 is on the ext3/4 and integrity fails for B1 (verified with PRAGMA integrity_check).

Comment: Clarification: integrity check on connection A results OK.
integrity check on connection B fails on A1.

Comment: Finally we found that the issue was in the memory file system implementation. The locking system was wrong.